# Deleting all files in document library PNP SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Hi I'm deleting all files and folders from a document library with the following code but errors in the console. However the files do get deleted. Any ideas as don't want to see the errors?

```
$items =Get-PnPListItem -List “test” -PageSize 1000

foreach ($item in $items)
{
try
{
Remove-PnPListItem -List “test” -Identity $item.Id -Force
Write-Host "Removing ListItemID=$($item.Id)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
catch
{
Write-Host “error”
}
}



Removing ListItemID=215
Remove-PnPListItem : Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
At line:7 char:1
+ Remove-PnPListItem -List “test” -Identity $item.Id -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Remove-PnPListItem], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.RemoveListItem

Removing ListItemID=216
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use For loop instead of Foreach below because the list item collection is dynamic :

```
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List “test” -PageSize 1000
For ($i = $items.Count-1; $i -ge 0; $i--)
{
    try
    {
        #Remove-PnPListItem -List "test" -Identity $items[$i].Id -Force
        Write-Host "Removing ListItemID=$($items[$i].Id)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "error"
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thats Great! It took about 12 seconds to delete 100 files.

Is there a way to delete a specific folder in the Library rather than everything in the library?

Comment: Happy to help ! To delete a folder, you can use [Remove-PnPFolder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpfolder?view=sharepoint-ps) command. You can accept it as answer so that it help others in the community !