# delete specific folder (subfoders and files) in document library

Tags: sharepoint-online

Following a [previous thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/267681/deleting-all-files-in-document-library-pnp-spo/267685#267685) 
I want to be able to delete a specific folder (subfolders and files) within a library. The only other thing is that it has a million items within the folder.

Any ideas on how the code below can be edited to target a folder?

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $siteUrl –Credentials (Get-Credential)

$items = Get-PnPListItem -List “test” -PageSize 1000
For ($i = $items.Count-1; $i -ge 0; $i--)
{
    try
    {
        Remove-PnPListItem -List "test" -Identity $items[$i].Id -Force
        Write-Host "Removing ListItemID=$($items[$i].Id)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "error"
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Remove-PnPFolder to delete folders and files/folders within the folder.

A demo for your reference:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl –Credentials (Get-Credential)
Remove-PnPFolder -name Test -Folder "/your library"
```

More information about this cmdlet, you can refer to:

[Remove-PnPFolder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpfolder?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: This only deletes folders files if under the list threshold. I have over a million files as mentioned in my original question. error Remove-PnPFolder : Cannot remove file "Client Folder". Error Code: 36

Comment: -Force switch gives same error

Comment: You can delete files within the folder in batch, then delete the folder. There is a blog for your reference: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/10/delete-all-list-items-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html